# my tablet tablet samsung GT-P7510 not use values-sw720dp-mdpi

Tags: java, android, xml, resolution, tablet

I have a file dimen.xml  in folder values-sw720dp-mdpi, but my tablet samsung GT-P7510 use folder values-sw720dp-xhdpi  why ?

Thank's for your responses

Comment: Using density qualifiers (e.g., `-mdpi`) for anything other than drawables is a significant code smell, because Android's rules for handling screen density are designed for drawables and do not work well for other resource types. Use any unit of measure other than `px` for your dimension resources, and you should not need density-specific values for those resources.

Comment: Thank's for your response but change px to dp and sp does't resolve my problem

besides folders values-sw600dp-mdpi and values-sw600dp-xhdpi works fine

Comment: "change px to dp and sp does't resolve my problem" -- feel free to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain what your problem is. "besides folders values-sw600dp-mdpi and values-sw600dp-xhdpi works fine" -- only on the handful of devices that you have tested, out of thousands.

Comment: No i was wrong with dp it work fine. thank's for your help